# Generate a sudoku puzzle with minimum number of entries that has exactly $k$ solutions

Tags: puzzle-creation, sudoku

Is there an algorithm to generate a sudoku puzzle having the minimum number of entries that has exactly $k>1$ solutions?  What is this minimum number of entries, as a function of $k$?  Given that the minimum number of entries for $k=1$ solutions is $17$, then surely the solution to this question is less than or equal to $17$.

Comment: FWIW: I disagree with @Jesse, I think this question *does* belong on this stack. Whether you'll get an answer or not, [given how much effort it took to prove k=1](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/426554/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/), is another matter...

Comment: @Alconja The first sentence threw me off. You cannot generate a puzzle minimising the number of puzzles generated. It does not make sense.

Comment: It should be a np problem.and it's not a puzzle it seems.

Comment: Solve for K where number of puzzles is minimised would make sense, but yeah, not a puzzle

Comment: @apm I don't think this is even in NP (Non-deterministic Polynomial time); given an answer, a brute force search is still needed to verify that the number of entries is minimal. In any case, [PSE is a site for those who create, solve, and study puzzles](/tour), so this question is definitely on-topic, even though it isn't a puzzle in itself.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been raised in 2006 on [this forum.](http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/minimum-number-of-clues-for-exactly-n-solutions-t3843.html)
Even "the big guys" of sudoku maths (Ed Russell and Fredrik Kjell) were unable to give a real answer.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :D